# Enable PHP's sockets extension, uncommenting on php.ini not working LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, package

[image: I intend to install a laravel package in my project but get " Install or enable PHP's sockets extension" error]

I have uncommented the same in my php.ini files, but I still get the same error.

[image: php.ini]

Edit:

located on C:\xampp\php\php.ini
The code shows all the extensions and the ones that I have uncommented. I can't point out what it is that I have missed

`php.ini`

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_extname.dll

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

I need your help in enabling the sockets. THANK YOU.

Comment: Have you restarted PHP service?

Comment: Yes.  I restarted apache

Comment: What about PHP? Which OS are you on? What version of PHP and how is your PHP installed?

Comment: PHP 7.3.27 , Windows 10, I am using xampp and it's a laravel project. Kindly check the edit with the `php.ini` file.